# Sending unsigned char[] over socket from c++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I'm trying to send a video stream over socket from a computer running C++ to one running Java. The images are being encoded as a 1d array of unsigned chars on the C++ (server side) and I'd like to receive such a stream of chars on the Java side in as efficient a way possible. But my understanding is that C++ unsigned chars range from 0–255 and that the `InputStream` class on the Java side only reads data as a `Byte` (-128–127). Would it then be that case that any pixel valued above 127 from C++ would wrap around into the negatives when receiving it on the Java client end?

If so, is there a quick fix, or perhaps a way to avoid reading the char[] into bytes that is still fairly quick? Maybe a `BufferedReader` that takes in the whole array as a string, splits it up, and converts to integers?

Comment: Why do you need a fix exactly? Can you show some code that shows why this is an issue that requires a fix? Normally there is no reason you should care about this.

Comment: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: A Java `byte` is identical to a C++ signed char.  Treating each datum as a signed or unsigned 8-bit value does not change the data.

Comment: If you want the unsigned value of an individual `byte`, there's [`Byte.toUnsignedInt(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-)

Comment: What David said above.  Don't worry about the type interpretation.  It's unsigned char on the C++ side and "byte" on the Java side.  In memory, it's still the same stream of bits.

Comment: Ah, okay—thanks @DavidSchwartz. I was just being apprehensive about possible problems before I tested it.